# What is the difference between aligned in displayed mode and starred align?

Tags: amsmath, align

I am confused in choosing one of the following approaches.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\sisetup{detect-all}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\parindent=0pt\relax
\begin{document}
The following calculation is a trivial example
\[
\begin{aligned}
q       &=CV                                \\
        &=\num{3e-20x1000}  \\
        &=\num{3e-17}
\end{aligned}
\]
The following calculation is a trivial example
\begin{align*}
q       &=CV                                \\
        &=\num{3e-20x1000}  \\
        &=\num{3e-17}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

What is the difference between `aligned` in displayed mode and starred `align`?

Edit:

If there is a difference and we have to show the substitution steps above or algebraic operation steps below, which one we have to use based on the internationally adopted convention?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
The following calculation is a trivial example
\[
\begin{aligned}
a(x+b)^2 - ab^2 &= a(x^2 + 2bx + b^2) - ab^2\\
                                &= ax^2 + 2abx + ab^2 - ab^2\\
                                &= ax^2 + 2abx
\end{aligned}
\]

The following calculation is a trivial example
\begin{align*}
a(x+b)^2 - ab^2 &= a(x^2 + 2bx + b^2) - ab^2\\
                                &= ax^2 + 2abx + ab^2 - ab^2\\
                                &= ax^2 + 2abx
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your first version is essentially a *single* equation (that contains several lines of aligned equations, but that is secondary). Your second version consists of *several* equations. This alters the spacing above and below that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\parindent=0pt\relax
\begin{document}
The following calculation is a trivial example
\hrule
\[
\begin{aligned}
q       &=CV                                \\
        &=3e-20x1000  \\
        &=3e-17
\end{aligned}
\]
\hrule

\bigskip

\hrule
\begin{align*}
q       &=CV                                \\
        &=3e-20x1000  \\
        &=3e-17
\end{align*}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

yields:
[image: display math versus align]

Usually you want the larger spacing around a block of several equations. Your second version is also conceptually clearer.

Comment: Out of topic comment: Conventionally, do we have to use separate equations to show the substitution steps?

Comment: @GarbageCollector Yes, I think so.

Comment: If I describe the steps in an algebraic solution, should these steps be a different equation each one (and not aligned), i.e. we don't use neither `align` nor `aligned`?

Answer (score 15):

This is in addition to the already existing answers.

One particular case where `aligned` environment is preferred over `align*` is when using `\parbox` inside a `tabular` package when `colortbl` package is loaded. This causes a bug which was patched by [Stephan Lehmke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/12850/stephan-lehmke) in my question [colortbl and amsmath conflict](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86211/colortbl-and-amsmath-conflict). In the same post, [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) mentioned in comment to [Peter Grill's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4301/peter-grill) answer that you can use positioning options like `t` and `b` in `aligned` which you cannot do in `align*`.

In `tabular`, you can do the following with `aligned`

```
\documentclass[preview,border=5]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\sisetup{detect-all}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\parindent=0pt\relax
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[t]{p{0.5\linewidth}l}
The following calculation is a trivial example
    & $
        \begin{aligned}[t]
        q       &=CV                                \\
                &=\num{3e-20x1000}  \\
                &=\num{3e-17}
        \end{aligned}
      $\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

as against the following with `align*`

```
\documentclass[preview,border=5]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\sisetup{detect-all}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\parindent=0pt\relax
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[t]{p{0.5\linewidth}l}
The following calculation is a trivial example
    & \parbox[t]{0.4\linewidth}{%
        \begin{align*}
        q       &=CV                                \\
                &=\num{3e-20x1000}  \\
                &=\num{3e-17}
        \end{align*}}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

When in `list` environments, with `aligned` you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\sisetup{detect-all}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\parindent=0pt\relax
\begin{document}
The following calculation is a trivial example
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
    \(
      \begin{aligned}
q       &=CV                                \\
        &=\num{3e-20x1000}  \\
        &=\num{3e-17}
      \end{aligned}
    \)

\item 
    \(
      \begin{aligned}[t]
    q       &=CV                                \\
            &=\num{3e-20x1000}  \\
            &=\num{3e-17}
      \end{aligned}
    \)

\item 
    \(
      \begin{aligned}[b]
    q       &=CV                                \\
            &=\num{3e-20x1000}  \\
            &=\num{3e-17}
      \end{aligned}
    \)
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

as against

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\sisetup{detect-all}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\parindent=0pt\relax
\begin{document}

The following calculation is a trivial example
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
    \begin{align*}
    q       &=CV                                \\
            &=\num{3e-20x1000}  \\
            &=\num{3e-17}
    \end{align*}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Apparently I have got a similar answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68231/19356).

Comment: You are right. I learned this feature from egreg's comment in my linked post. I put this in my edit.

Answer (score 9):

As you've noticed, the `aligned` environment is meant to be part of a larger displayed math environment (which is why you put it in between `\[` and `\]`), while the `align*` environment is a freestanding displayed math environment.  For the use you made of them in your example, they're essentially equivalent.  The `aligned` environment can be used in many other situations, though, in which `align*` wouldn't work at all.

For example:

```
\begin{displaymath}
  \text{A simple example:}
  \qquad
  \begin{aligned}
  q       &=CV                \\
          &=\num{3e-20x1000}  \\
          &=\num{3e-17}
  \end{aligned}
\end{displaymath}
```

or

```
\begin{displaymath}
  \begin{aligned}
  q       &=CV                                \\
          &=\num{3e-20x1000}  \\
          &=\num{3e-17}
  \end{aligned}
  \qquad\text{and}\qquad
  \begin{gathered}
    a = b + c\\
    \sin^{2}x + \cos^{2}x = 1
  \end{gathered}
\end{displaymath}
```

Comment: Would be useful to show how one can use the `aligned` environment in a manner that illustrates something the `align*` environment can not do.

Answer (score 7):

"What is the difference between aligned in displayed mode and starred align?"

I'm adding this as the other answers seem not to have mentioned it (from the amsmath package users guide):

Whereas *align* produces a structure whose width is the full line width, *aligned* gives a width that is the actual width of the contents, thus it can be used as a component in a containing expression, e.g. for putting the entire alignment in a parenthesis.

E.g.

```
\begin{equation*}
\left.\begin{aligned}
B’&=-\partial\times E,\\
E’&=\partial\times B - 4\pi j,
\end{aligned}
\right\}
\qquad \text{Maxwell’s equations}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

it makes no sense to compare `aligned` and `align*`. The first one is used if you want *one* equation number for several lines. This is the reason why `aligned` is used as part of `align` or a similar environment.